# Infinite while loop with await functions only executing once

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I have an infinite loop that runs 2 functions, but when I run the loop it only executes the functions once. Does anyone know why?

This is the loop

```
while(true){
  await getPorticoPulseira();
  await sleep(3000);
}
```

This is the sleep function

```
function sleep(ms){
    return new Promise( resolve => setTimeout(resolve,ms) );
}
```

This is the getPorticoPulseira function

```
function getPorticoPulseira() {
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    var { PythonShell } = require("python-shell");
    var path = require("path");

    var options = {
        scriptPath: path.join(__dirname, "../_engine/"),
    };

    var readrfid = new PythonShell("lerpulseira.py", options);

    var nrseriepulseira = 0;
    readrfid.on("message", function (message) {
        console.log(message);
        nrseriepulseira = message;
    });
});
```

}

Comment: You never call `resolve` or `reject` in `getPorticoPulseira`.

Comment: I'm still very noob at callbacks, promises... I actually don't know where to call the resolve and reject... Could you please help me?

Comment: the question is really more about how promise works but if i where u i would return the stream and use the async iterator on the stream and do `for await (const msg of stream) {...}`

Comment: Instead of the while loop? I'm sorry about my questions but I'm still a noob with javascript

Comment: Thanks guys I solved the problem